# How to refer Spark RDD element multiple times using underscore notation?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to refer Spark RDD element multiple times using underscore notations.
For example I need to convert RDD[String] to RDD[(String, Int)]. I can create anonymous function using function variables but I would like to do this using Underscore notation. How I can achieve this.

PFB sample code.

```
val x = List("apple", "banana")
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(x)
// Working
val rdd2 = rdd1.map(x => (x, x.length))

// Not working
val rdd3 = rdd1.map((_, _.length))
```

Why does the last line above not work?

Answer (score 1):

An underscore or (more commonly) a placeholder syntax is a marker of a single input parameter. It's nice to use for simple functions, but can get tricky to get right with two or more.

You can find the definitive answer in the Scala language specification's [Placeholder Syntax for Anonymous Functions](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions):

> An expression (of syntactic category `Expr`) may contain embedded underscore symbols _ at places where identifiers are legal. Such an expression represents an anonymous function where subsequent occurrences of underscores denote successive parameters.

Note that one underscore references one input parameter, two underscores are for two different input parameters and so on.

With that said, you **cannot** use the placeholder twice and expect that they'll reference the same input parameter. That's not how it works in Scala and hence the compiler error.

```
// Not working
val rdd3 = rdd1.map((_, _.length))
```

The above is equivalent to the following:

```
// Not working
val rdd3 = rdd1.map { (a: String, b: String) => (a, b.length)) }
```

which is clearly incorrect as `map` expects a function of one input parameter.